# Create a constant pulse animation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sun with a pulsing animation. However, I'm having trouble with the intervals of the pulse. Two pulses should always be moving with the transition. Also the sun shouldn't be standing without a pulse.

```css
.pulse {
  margin: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cca92c;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
  position: relative;
}

.pulse::before {
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse2 2.5s infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.pulse:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nb-infosys-sun">
  <span class="pulse"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to have 3 elements if you want 2 of them to always be visible. Then you can adjust timings, so that whenever 1st one reaches the vanishing point, 3rd one starts out.

Comment: Do you only need help with the transition of the pulse as shown in the example above? i mean the example shown resembles more with a location pointer rather than the sun

Comment: Have one more element &::after and just add an animation delay to 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got after adding `animation-delay`:

```
.pulse::before {
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse2 1s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**[Here is the JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nfa59bh4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can add some animation delay to adjust timing of both pulse as below snippet

```css
.pulse {
  margin: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cca92c;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite both;
  position: relative;
}

.pulse::before {
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  animation: pulse2 2s linear 1s infinite both;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.pulse:hover {
  animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(204, 169, 44, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nb-infosys-sun">
  <span class="pulse"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Pulse Animation CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="pulse">code_snail</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #262626;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pulse {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgb(255, 0, 64);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 64, 0.7), 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 64, 0.7);
    }

    40% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(255, 0, 64, 0), 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 64, 0.7);
    }

    80% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 50px rgba(255, 0, 64, 0), 0 0 0 30px rgba(255, 0, 64, 0);
    }

    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 64, 0), 0 0 0 30px rgba(255, 0, 64, 0);
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: css pulse animation | codesnail.com]

[codesnail.com](https://www.codesnail.com/2019/07/css-pulse-animation.html)